# What is "Anapanasati" day which is coming on this November 14?

Tags: lay-buddhism, anapanasati

What is "Anapanasati" day? I used to fasting on Uposatha, I became unable to do after my health got down. Last time I had asked to what to do on Uposatha Day but as I mentioned above and still unable to do; but now I've to practice seriously and go to Vihara on Anapansati day so is it same as Uposatha ? And if it is have to practice, then can I go for it in the middle stage or from the beginning? But anyhow I want to practicing and feel spirit of it when I loosed of my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the anniversary of Buddha delivering the *Anapanasati Sutta* (Sutra on the Mindfulness of Breathing), an important Sutra about meditation

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uposatha#Special_uposatha_days

(Sorry but I don't know enough to answer the other questions you asked, but I hope this answer and reference helps to some extent)